# PDF upload by user in Drupal

Tags: drupal, forms, pdf, file-upload, drupal-5

I am developing a site for an International Conference. I want the registered users to upload their research papers in pdf format using a form. I have no previous experiences working with a CMS.

Comment: Learn Drupal, at least core concepts. Otherwise you are going to get into trouble as things get complicated.

Comment: See..! I am a PHP programmer and have done the same through my own PHP code and stored in the db as BLOB, so I know the core concepts and since I get poor internet I couldn't search for more modules., So just needed a help from you guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only have few experience of Drupal and CMS in general and only want to quickly add a form to collect files from registered users and only use Drupal as a basic CMS for your website, the [Webform](http://drupal.org/project/webform) module is probably the easiest solution. It allows you to build a forms for PDF files and additional information submission. The submissions can be stored in the database, sent by email or even exported to a spreadsheet or a CSV file. Registred users are even able to edit their submissions.

Another solution is to use the [CCK](http://drupal.org/project/cck) and the [FileField](http://drupal.org/project/filefield) modules to build a content type for submissions and allow registred users create new content using this type. If you go this way, you can build many additional feature. You can use [taxonomies](http://drupal.org/handbook/modules/taxonomy) to organize submissions by category and/org tags. You can allow users to view, comment, [rate](http://drupal.org/project/fivestar), or [flag](http://drupal.org/project/flag) submissions. With [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) you can create lists of submissions by state (accepted, rejected), category, etc.

Comment: Used webform, the simplest way to do it :) Thank you very much, I owe you a lot :)

Answer (score 5):

Create a 'Research' content type.

Enable Upload module

Enable File Attachments for the Research content type.

Allow registered users to upload files, and create new Research nodes, and edit own Research nodes

This would be the quickest way. If you are using CCK, you could create a CCK FileField instead, and tell it to only accept pdf files.